# Make the image in nth-child div a clickthrough link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, squarespace

Im trying to add a link to several images on my squarespace site using jquery. However they dont share a class and i cant add one as im using squarespace so i can only add custom css or javascript.

So the way im trying to do it is by selecting the parent div which has the class name ".ProductItem-gallery-slides-item" and then its second child which is also a div and then the image inside that. Once I selected the correct element I add a click function which is supposed to link to a page with more information about the image. I already tried another way using .warp() but im very new to jquery i didn't quite understand it nor did it work.

The html hierarchy:

```
<div class="ProductItem-gallery-slides-item">
  <div>
    <img 1>
  </div>
  <div>
    <img 2>
  </div>
</div>
```

My JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".ProductItem-gallery-slides-item:nth-child(2)").children('img').click(function(){
      window.location = 'https://uk5-shop.com/paris-pink';
    });
  }
```

The result should be a clickable image.

Hope I asked this right any hello is hugely appreciated. Kind Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector is incorrect. Use

```
$(".ProductItem-gallery-slides-item > div:nth-child(2) > img").on("click", ...
```

Since you want to get the second child div of `ProductItem-gallery-slides-item`.

Also your code is missing a closing `)`. 
And a side note: `$().click(...)` is deprecated. Use `$().on("click", ...)` instead (see code below).

**Demo:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".ProductItem-gallery-slides-item > div:nth-child(2) > img").on("click", function(){
        // window.location = 'https://uk5-shop.com/paris-pink';
        // console.log for demo
        console.log("Second image clicked!");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="ProductItem-gallery-slides-item">
    <div>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/140x100.png">
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/140x100.png">
    </div>
</div>
```